Не работает модуль возврата в программе
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если в начальном окне вбить 2 и нажать на кнопку Назад внутри окна, программа возвращает меня к главному окну как и должно быть, но если вбить в строку ввода снова 2, то в консоль выводит Введёное значение является числом, тоесть меня не возвращают в функцию OkEdit, а просто выводят все label что нужны, хоть я и вписал self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OkEdit(self.Main_enter.text())).
Знаю что это можно решить обходными путями, но хотелось как можно короче.
Простите за размер кода, пытался сократить как мог, но из-за словаря получился большим, а у меня он находится в другом файле.
Буду признателен если поможете и распишите в чём у меня ошибки.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import random as rd
import os 
import sys

gogo_dict = {}
number = {
  "А":1, "а":1, "A":1, "a":1,
  "Б":2, "б":2, "B":2, "b":2,
  "В":3, "в":3, "C":3, "c":3,
  "Г":4, "г":4, "D":4, "d":4,
  "Д":5, "д":5, "E":5, "e":5,
  "Е":6, "е":6, "F":6, "f":6,
  "Ё":7, "ё":7, "G":7, "g":7,
  "Ж":8, "ж":8, "H":8, "h":8,
  "З":9, "з":9, "I":9, "i":9,
  "И":10, "и":10, "J":10, "j":10,
  "Й":11, "й":11, "K":11, "k":11,
  "К":12, "к":12, "L":12, "l":12,
  "Л":13, "л":13, "M":13, "m":13,
  "М":14, "м":14, "N":14, "n":14,
  "Н":15, "н":15, "O":15, "o":15,
  "О":16, "о":16, "P":16, "p":16,
  "П":17, "п":17, "Q":17, "q":17,
  "Р":18, "р":18, "R":18, "r":18,
  "С":19, "с":19, "S":19, "s":19,
  "Т":20, "т":20, "T":20, "t":20,
  "У":21, "у":21, "U":21, "u":21,
  "Ф":22, "ф":22, "V":22, "v":22,
  "Х":23, "х":23, "W":23, "w":23,
  "Ц":24, "ц":24, "X":24, "x":24,
  "Ч":25, "ч":25, "Y":25, "y":25,
  "Ш":26, "ш":26, "Z":26, "z":26,
  "Щ":27, "щ":27,
  "Ъ":28, "ъ":28,
  "Ы":29, "ы":29,
  "Ь":30, "ь":30,
  "Э":31, "э":31,
  "Ю":32, "ю":32,
  "Я":33, "я":33,
  " ":0,       
  "_":1,
  "-":1,
  '.':1,
            }

class App(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.Main_enter = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.Main_enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(255, 530, 300, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.Main_enter.setFont(font)
    self.Main_enter.setObjectName('Main_enter')
    self.Main_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
    self.Main_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(557, 530, 60, 32))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.Main_btn.setFont(font)
    self.Main_btn.setObjectName("Main_btn")
    self.central_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
    self.central_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect())
    self.Main_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
    self.Main_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 760, 30 ))
    self.Main_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(15)
    self.Main_label.setFont(font)
    self.Main_label.setObjectName("Main_label")
    self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
    self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 450, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.label2.setFont(font)
    self.label2.setObjectName('Label2')
    self.back_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
    self.back_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 50, 30 ))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.back_label.setFont(font)
    self.back_label.setObjectName("back_label")
    self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
    self.back_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 560, 70, 30))
    self.End_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
    self.End_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 760, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(11)
    self.back_btn.setFont(font)
    self.back_btn.setObjectName("back_label")
    self.End_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.add_function()
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.Main_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбор программы"))
    self.Main_enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
    self.Main_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ок"))
    self.Main_text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
    self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбирать имя по его среднему значению букв - 2"))
    self.back_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Назад"))
    
def add_function(self):
    self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OkEdit(self.Main_enter.text()))
    self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.back_prj)

def OkEdit(self, number):
        if number == "2":
            print('Программа 2')
            self.Main_label.setText("Программа 2")
            self.label3.clear();self.Main_enter.clear(); self.label2.clear(); self.label1.clear()
            self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.request_name(self.Main_enter.text()))
            self.request_name(pain="Словарь")

def back_prj(self):
    self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OkEdit(self.Main_enter.text()))
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
               
class Stert_prj(App):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()   
    
def request_name(self, pain):    # Функция осуществляющая пересчёт имён
    try:
        numbers = list(pain)
        numberse = number
        ordered_dict = {}                 
        for item in numbers:
            ordered_dict[item] = numberse[item]
        summa_nums = round(sum(ordered_dict.values()) / len(ordered_dict.values()))
        gogo_dict.update({pain:summa_nums})
        sorted(gogo_dict)
        print("Список: ")
        for keys, val in gogo_dict.items():
            print(keys, '-', val,)
        self.Main_enter.clear()     
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Введёное значение является числом")

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
 ex = Stert_prj()
 ex.setupUi(MainWindow)
 MainWindow.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())


Похоже вы совсем запутались в своих коллбэках. Вы назначили коллбэком для кнопки Main_btn метод OkEdit. После ввода числа 2 при первом вызове этого коллбэка вы назначаете еще и второй коллбэк:
self.Main_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.request_name(self.Main_enter.text()))

Далее вызываете метод request_name - тут видимо работает так как вы задумывали, но при каждом следующем нажатии на кнопку срабатывает сразу два коллбэка - один из них это выше указанный вызов метода request_name c пустой строкой в качестве аргумента, а когда строка пустая - вы получаете ошибку в этом месте:
summa_nums = round(sum(ordered_dict.values()) / len(ordered_dict.values()))

Внимательнее читайте свой код, разберитесь какой метод у вас за что отвечает.
